# How to map Table-Per-Hierarchy with NHibernate 3.2 ConventionModelMapper

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using NHibernate 3.2 mapping by code/convention and am having trouble mapping simple table-per-hierachy inheritance.  My base class is LookupBase and there are more than a dozen classes that derive from this base class.  I'd like the class model to map to a single table in the database with a discriminator column (The discriminator column will contain the name of the respective concrete class).

The base class, LookupBase is in a different assembly from the concrete classes.

Here are how the concrete classes are implemented:

```
namespace ROWMobile.Domain
{
    public class NotificationMethod : LookupBase
    {
    }

    public class ContactMethod : LookupBase
    {
    }

    public class ContactType : LookupBase
    {
    }

...
```

As you can see, there are no additional properties in the concrete classes - they inherit all properties from LookupBase.

```
private HbmMapping GenerateMappings()
{
    ConventionModelMapper relationalMapper = new ConventionModelMapper();

    var baseLookupType = typeof(LookupBase);

    relationalMapper.IsRootEntity((t, declared) => t.BaseType != null && (t.BaseType == typeof(object)));

    relationalMapper.IsTablePerClassHierarchy((t, declared) =>
       {
            if (t == typeof(LookupBase))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

    var mapping = relationalMapper.CompileMappingFor(GetDomainEntities());
    return mapping;
}

private static IEnumerable<Type> GetDomainEntities()
{
    Assembly domainAssembly = typeof(Event).Assembly;

    IList<Type> baseEntities = new List<Type>();

    baseEntities.Add(typeof(LookupBase));

    IEnumerable<Type> domainEntities = from t in domainAssembly.GetTypes()
                                        where (IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(typeof(LookupBase), t) 
                                        && !t.IsGenericType)
                                        select t;

    IEnumerable<Type> allEntities = domainEntities.Concat(baseEntities);

    return allEntities;
}

static bool IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(Type generic, Type toCheck) 
{ 
    while (toCheck != null && toCheck != typeof(object)) 
    { 
        var cur = toCheck.IsGenericType ? toCheck.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : toCheck; 
        if (generic == cur) 
        { 
            return true; 
        } 
        toCheck = toCheck.BaseType; 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

I call the above code like this:

```
HbmMapping generatedMappings = GenerateMappings();

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Serialize(generatedMappings));

NhConfiguration.AddDeserializedMapping(generatedMappings, null);
```

Then, I have a test that creates the schema:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GenerateSchema()
{
    NHibernateConfigurator nhc = new NHibernateConfigurator();
    nhc.BuildSessionFactory<MsSql2008Dialect>();
    SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(nhc.NhConfiguration);
    schemaExport.Execute(true, true, false);
}
```

When I Xml Serialize the HbmMapping produced, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
<class name="Marathon.MobileApplication.Client.LookupBase, MobileApplication.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="LookupBases" abstract="true">
  <id name="Id" type="Int32" />
  <discriminator />
  <property name="Value" />
  <property name="InternalId" />
</class>
<joined-subclass name="ROWMobile.Domain.NotificationMethod, ROWMobile.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" extends="Marathon.MobileApplication.Client.LookupBase, MobileApplication.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
  <key column="notificationmethod_key" />
</joined-subclass>
<joined-subclass name="ROWMobile.Domain.ContactMethod, ROWMobile.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" extends="Marathon.MobileApplication.Client.LookupBase, MobileApplication.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
  <key column="contactmethod_key" />
</joined-subclass>
<joined-subclass name="ROWMobile.Domain.ContactType, ROWMobile.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" extends="Marathon.MobileApplication.Client.LookupBase, MobileApplication.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
  <key column="contacttype_key" />
</joined-subclass>

....
```

Which produces a LookupBases table that has the discriminator table, but it also produces a table for each concrete class.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Also, does anyone know of any documentation available for the mapping by code/convention feature introduced in NHibernate 3.2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding the hbm for the parts that just dont seem to work correctly?  I know it's a hack but it seems to work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I actually solved the problem by switching to Fluent NHibernate.